# How to transfer Data between pages?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I know this question have been asked but my situation a little different. 
All of my Data are saved inside a C# page like this:

```
    public class RestaurantsDataInfo
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string picture { get; set; }
    public string openclosetime { get; set; }
    public string state { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
public class RestaurantManager
{
    public static List<RestaurantsDataInfo> GetRestaurants()
    {
        var restaurant = new List<RestaurantsDataInfo>();
        restaurant.Add(new RestaurantsDataInfo { name = "Pizzeria", address = "22 - Vo Van Ngan Str", openclosetime = "8 AM to 9 PM", picture = "Assets/Cover7.jpg", state = "Online" });
        restaurant.Add(new RestaurantsDataInfo { name = "BBQ Kings", address = "55 - Vo Van Ngan Str", openclosetime = "8 AM to 10 PM", picture = "Assets/Cover6.jpg", state = "Online" });
        restaurant.Add(new RestaurantsDataInfo { name = "Lotteria", address = "200 - Vo Van Ngan Str", openclosetime = "8 AM to 8:30 PM", picture = "Assets/Cover5.png", state = "Online" });
        restaurant.Add(new RestaurantsDataInfo { name = "KFC", address = "90 - Vo Van Ngan Str", openclosetime = "8 AM to 8 PM", picture = "Assets/Cover4.png", state = "Online" });
        restaurant.Add(new RestaurantsDataInfo { name = "Mugsy Dogs", address = "112 - Linh Trung Str", openclosetime = "8 AM to 8:30 PM", picture = "Assets/Cover9.png", state = "Online" });
        restaurant.Add(new RestaurantsDataInfo { name = "American Hot Dog", address = "04 - Duong So 5 Str", openclosetime = "8 AM to 8:30 PM", picture = "Assets/Cover10.jpg", state = "Online" });
        restaurant.Add(new RestaurantsDataInfo { name = "Burger King", address = "404 - Duong So 6 Str", openclosetime = "24 hours", picture = "Assets/Cover11.png", state = "Online" });
        return restaurant;
    }
}
```

Here is the Page that bind all the data:

```
            <GridView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ListOfRestaurant" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="ListOfRestaurant_ItemClick" ScrollViewer.IsScrollInertiaEnabled="True" ItemsSource="{x:Bind RES}">
            <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:RestaurantsDataInfo">
                    <StackPanel Width="197" Height="240">
                        <Image x:Name="ResPic" Source="{x:Bind picture}" Stretch="Fill" Height="150" Width="150"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="RestaurantName" Text="{x:Bind name}" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="Brown"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind state}" Margin="3" Foreground="Green"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind address}" Margin="3" Foreground="BlueViolet"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind openclosetime}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="3" Foreground="Salmon"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemTemplate>
        </GridView>
```

Here is the code back-end of it:

```
        private void ListOfRestaurant_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = (RestaurantsDataInfo)e.ClickedItem;
        var title = item.name;
        var container = ListOfRestaurant.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
        if (container != null)
        {
            //find the image
            var root = (FrameworkElement)container.ContentTemplateRoot;
            var image = (UIElement)root.FindName("ResPic");



            //prepare the animation
            ConnectedAnimationService.GetForCurrentView().PrepareToAnimate("Image", image);
        }
        switch (title)
        {
            case "KFC":

                Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailRestaurant), _storeditem = item.picture);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Now I want to navigate to "DetailRestaurant" and send to that page the information that in the RestaurantDataInfo so that the Detail Page can show all the content base on what restaurant I'm clicking

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to pass in the "ID" of the restaurant you want to display data for:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailRestaurant),"KFC");
```

And now on the other page's `OnNavigatedTo` access the parameter and then the detail info from the `static` collection:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var info = RestaurantManager.GetRestaurants().
        FirstOrDefault( r => r.name == e.Parameter?.ToString());
}
```

Comment: "KFC" is the ID ?

Comment: Yes, that is the ID. I just used KFC to match your sample code